# Android Client Implementation Errors

Tags: java, android, tcp, client-server

Trying To let an android device get data from a server I have:

```
RetreiveFeedTask DoStuff=new RetreiveFeedTask();
            try{
            Work=(DoStuff.execute(Exec)).get();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {System.out.print(e+"");}
```

Async Implementation:

```
class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void , String> {

//private Exception e;
String GotBack="empty";
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try{ 
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.66", 2727);   
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();       
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);    
            BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            output.println(params[0]);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            GotBack="OverWritten";
            GotBack=input.readLine();
            socket.close();                                                 
            }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.print(e+"");}
    return GotBack;
}
```

}

My server is sending the ACK:
"1\n"

But what I get on the screen is "Overwritten" which is the value before I read data from the server.

Any idea why?

**Update**

I was closing the output socket so it was throwing an exception. Now Im not getting errors but the value I get is empty. Any idea why?

New Code:

```
class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void , String> {

//private Exception e;
String GotBack="empty";
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try{ 
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.66", 2727);   
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();       
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);    
            BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            output.println(params[0]);
            output.flush();
            String read="";
            while((read=input.readLine())!=null)
            {
            GotBack+=read;
            }
            output.close();
            socket.close();                                                 
            }
        catch(Exception e){Log.e("MyApp","exception",e);}
    return GotBack;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Executing `input.readLine();` must have thrown an exception which you handled and printed. The value of `GotBack` is now "OverWritten" which is returned on `return GotBack;`.

Comment: True. I places GotBack="Overwritten" after readline and it returned "empty". But could the error be?